# Gridview error message when trying to delete or edit

Tags: c#, asp.net

The error message I get is:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No value given for one or more required parameters.

I did a little reading so I went into my Boundfield and set everything to readonly. That did not fix it. I counted my parameters and they seem to match. So I am really confused as these two fixes are typically what are suggested.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Students] WHERE (([Email] = ?) OR ([Email] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL))" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Students] ([LastName], [FirstName], [MiddleInitial], [Phone], [Email], [GPA]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Students]" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Students] SET [LastName] = ?, [FirstName] = ?, [MiddleInitial] = ?, [Phone] = ?, [GPA] = ? WHERE (([Email] = ?) OR ([Email] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL))">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="MiddleInitial" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="GPA" Type="Double" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="MiddleInitial" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="GPA" Type="Double" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

In both the cases (editing and deleting), you have a mystery parameter with no value:

```
DeleteCommand =
  "DELETE FROM [Students] WHERE (([Email] = ?) OR ([Email] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL))" 

UpdateCommand =
  "UPDATE [Students] SET [LastName] = ?, [FirstName] = ?, [MiddleInitial] = ?, [Phone] = ?, [GPA] = ? WHERE (([Email] = ?) OR ([Email] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL))">
```

I'd say you need to figure out why both commands have `OR ([Email] IS NULL AND ? IS NULL))` on the end of them. Or just try removing that part of the command if you can manually edit the code you posted.